# Repository pattern with paging library

Tags: android, android-paging-library

I have a problem when apply [Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/) to my project which is using ([Repository Pattern](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-dagger/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/data/source))

In my repository, I already have `UsersDataSource`, `UsersRepository`, `UserLocalDataSource`, `UserRemoteDataSource`

To use [Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/), I see we need to create class like `...DataSource extend ItemKeyedDataSource` and `...DataSourceFactory extend DataSource.Factory` (I am follow tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@Ahmed.AbdElmeged/android-paging-library-with-rxjava-and-rest-api-e5c229fd70ba) to learn [Paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/)).
It **conflict** with my current repository class.

Is there any good way to apply [Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/) with `Repository` pattern.
I just learn paging library. Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm struggling to use Paging + RxJava + Repository pattern.

Answer (score 0):

There is an advice from Android developers page how to accomplish such architecture:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/#network-with-database-data-arch
You can find link to appropriate github repo and even a codelab there.